# Typescript Error when passing the rest prop {...others} to component of material-ui

Tags: typescript, material-ui, destructuring

I have created a UITooltip based on Tooltip component of material-ui. Here is my component:

```
import React, { FC } from "react"

import { Tooltip, TooltipProps } from "@material-ui/core"

import { useUITooltipStyles } from "./UITooltip.styles"

export type UITooltipVariantEnum = "primary" | "secondary"
export type UITooltipPlacementEnum =
  | "bottom"
  | "bottom-start"
  | "bottom-end"
  | "top"
  | "top-start"
  | "top-end"

export interface UITooltipProps extends Omit<TooltipProps, "id" | "placement"> {
  id: string
  variant?: UITooltipVariantEnum
  placement?: UITooltipPlacementEnum
}

const UITooltip: FC<UITooltipProps> = (props) => {
  const {
    id,
    variant = "secondary",
    placement = "bottom",
    children,
    ...others
  } = props
  const classes = useUITooltipStyles()

  return (
    <>
      {children && (
        <Tooltip
          aria-label={`${id}-tooltip`}
          data-cy={`${id}-tooltip`}
          classes={{
            tooltip: classes[variant]
          }}
          placement={placement as UITooltipPlacementEnum}
          {...others}
        >
          {children}
        </Tooltip>
      )}
    </>
  )
}

export default UITooltip
```

But I have this typescript error over {...others}

```
Type ...Omit<UITooltipProps & {children?: ReactNode}, "variant" | "id" | "placement" | "children"> is not assignable to type React.ReactElement<any, any>
```

Can someone explain to me why?

I think maybe there is an error in the way I declared the interface `UITooltipProps` and `FC<UITooltipProps>`